# How can I know the correct size of a std::seed_seq?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

For space reasons in the title I had to abuse the terminology a bit. Bear a moment.

`std::seed_seq` is used to seed the pseudo-random generators. Usually I prepare a `std::array` of `uint32_t` and fill it in of really random numbers (via `std::random_device`*) and pass the begin and end iterators to a `std::seed_seq` (see the example code).

The question is, given a certain pseudo random generator (e.g., `std::mt19937`) how can I know the correct size of the array to seed at its best? 
About `std::mt19937`, since the state size is 19937 bits I guess it is 624 `uint32_t`s, is it the case? And what is the general way to know?

```
std::mt19937 init_mersenne_twister() {                                        
    //624 is the internal state sequence size of mt19937
    std::array<std::uint32_t, 624> seed_bits{};                               

    std::random_device real_random{};                                         
    std::generate(seed_bits.begin(), seed_bits.end(), std::ref(real_random)); 
    std::seed_seq wrapped_seed_bits(seed_bits.begin(), seed_bits.end());      

    return std::mt19937(wrapped_seed_bits);                                   
}
```

*I am aware that random_device might not be available, but that's not the point of the question.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister, it look like 2^19937 is the *cycle*, and it has no relation to the seed

Comment: I think that the two concepts are connected. In the Initialization section it's explained that the state is n values of w bits each. And for the std::mt19937 those are indeed 624 and 32.

Comment: For std::mt19937 you can use std::mt19937::state_size. For others you will have to read the Standard to see the size of the internal state. However, in my opinion it doesn't make sense to seed std::mt19937 with 19968 bits of entropy. 256 bits of entropy should be sufficient for any purpose. You can't distinguish between two instances of std::mt19937, one seeded with 256 bits of entropy and one with 19968 bits of entropy.

Comment: I don't know your definition of "any purpose," but 2^256 starting seeds are not enough to get all the possible shuffling of a 60 elements array... Shuffling, btw, is exactly my use case.Since factorial grows so fast, even 2^19937 is barely enough for a 2000 elements array.